# Suppress ADO Security Warning in JavaScript/HTM Page

Tags: javascript, ms-access, activex, ado, activexobject

I have a fully functioning site stored on a network drive along with an Access Database which acts as the site's database.
Due to lack of server side code, I am forced to use JavaScript to create an ADO ActiveX object to connect to the database. This works.

The problem I am having is that whenever the user opens the site an ADO Security warning appears asking if they trust the site. If they press 'Cancel' the error thrown is: `Safety settings on this computer prohibit accessing a data source on another domain` however the database is stored in the same network directory as the site... If they press 'OK' the site opens fine.

Is there any way of stopping this warning from appearing?

Comment: Did you see this article? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313239

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I can't modify the security settings of the browser as it is controlled by a group policy.

Comment: @OverMind thanks so much for posting this, i've spent way to much time trying to figure this out and that articles solution was finally what worked for me.

Comment: Can you please share the solution

Comment: The solution without a GPO in the way of things is to go into IE's Internet Options, Security tab, for the Internet/Intranet zones, select Custom, and select Enable on "Access data source across domains". Problem comes in when you're running a script that should not even be doing that, but you get the error, anyway - like me, and probably Duncan.  For me, we aren't allowed to modify that setting.  My issue with it, is we should not even have to.  I just want data from the same domain I'm on, but it still does the error, anyway.

Comment: Related on the security settings portion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177060/hta-safety-settings-on-this-computer-prohibit-accessing-a-data-source-on-anot

Comment: Related on the JavaScript/Access connection side of this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729210/how-to-create-intranet-website-accessing-database-dynamically-without-server-or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue, and it was maddening me that there were others also on SO with no answer - and I found out some info that should help some people, and I have a workaround:

The issue with running this code from a web page is that it is bound by the security controls associated with that browser.  The website user probably wouldn't get the same error if they used a different browser - and they are probably getting the error in IE, if I had to guess.  In IE, there's a security control called "Access data source across domains", which is in the Miscellaneous section, if you go under **Tools > Internet Options, Security** tab, select the applicable zone for the site (probably **Intranet**, but this can be confirmed by looking on the IE status bar at the bottom while you are on the site, to see what zone is being applied), and select **Custom Level**.  The problem comes in if the workstations are administered by GPO - Custom Level is greyed out.  If not, you can find the setting, select **Enable** on the applicable client workstations that are accessing the site, and you're done.

#### If it's administered by GPO, and you are an domain admin capable of making such changes:

For the applicable OU in Active Directory Users & Computers for the client workstations where you want to make the change felt, right-click it and find the GPOs & edit.  It is under:  **Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Internet Control Panel > Security Page > Intranet Zone** (probably) > first option: **Access data sources across domains**.  Right-click it and select **Edit**.  Select the **Enabled** radio button, then select **Enabled** in the dropdown.

Select **Apply** and **OK**.

If the client workstation does not get the update, either reboot, or do `gpupdate /force` on a command line to force a GPO update and reboot.

#### If it's administered by GPO, and you are NOT a domain admin capable of making such changes:

Go with a VBScript, instead.  You can write a separate VBScript file with the connection, and you can even call it from JavaScript.  Below is a script that has an ADO Connection that I pulled from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/b160d928-fb9e-4c49-a194-f2e5a3e806ae as an example of how to format it.  Granted, it is to AD and not Access, but the concept is the same:

```
Option Explicit 

Dim objGroup 

'VERIFY A GROUP NAME WAS PASSED 
If wscript.arguments.count <> 1 Then 
  wscript.echo "NO GROUP PASSED" 
  wscript.echo "Usage:  scriptName <groupSamAccountName>" 
  wscript.quit 
End If 

'BIND TO THE GROUP   
Set objGroup = getGroup(wscript.Arguments(0)) 

'ENUMERATE THE GROUPS MEMBERS 
enumMembers objGroup, "" 

Function getGroup(strGroupName) 
  Dim objConn, objRecSet, strQueryString, objRootDSE, strQueryFrom 
  Const adsOpenStatic = 3 

  Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE") 
  strQueryFrom = "LDAP://" & objRootDSE.get("defaultNamingContext") 

  Set objConn = wscript.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
  objConn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject" 
  objConn.Open 

  strQueryString = "SELECT AdsPath FROM '" & strQueryFrom & "' WHERE samAccountName = '" & strGroupName & "'" 

  Set objRecSet = wscript.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 

  objRecSet.Open strQueryString, objConn, adsOpenStatic 

  If objRecSet.recordCount = 1 Then 
     Set getGroup = GetObject(objRecSet("AdsPath")) 
  Else 
     wscript.echo ucase(strGroupName) & " was not found in the domain. (" & objRootDSE.get("defaultNamingContext") & ")" 
     wscript.quit 
  End If 
End Function 

Sub enumMembers(byRef objGroup, strInheritedFrom) 
  Dim objMember 

  For Each objMember In objGroup.Members 
    If lcase(objMember.class) = "group" Then 
      enumMembers objMember, objMember.samAccountName 
    Else 
      If objMember.displayname <> "" Then 
         If strInheritedFrom = "" Then 
             wscript.echo objMember.displayname 
         Else 
             wscript.echo objMember.displayname & " (From NESTED GROUP:  " & strInheritedFrom & ")" 
         End If 
         Else 
           If strInheritedFrom = "" Then  
               wscript.echo objMember.samAccountName 
           Else 
               wscript.echo objMember.samAccountName & " (From NESTED GROUP:  " & strInheritedFrom & ")" 
           End If 
        End If 
     End If 
  Next 
End Sub
```

In my case, it was when I placed this block into an HTA (which runs in a browser) and ran getGroup() with a particular group name from a button click event that I got my error.  I wasn't even trying to get a group from a different domain!  It didn't matter!  So I had to pull this out into its own VBScript and run it on its own.  I took the output I got and wrote it to a file (by storing the responses to a variable, with `& vbCrLf` after each result for a line break after each one, and sending it to code from here:  http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/vbscript_file_opentextfile.htm ).  I won't include that code as it's even farther down the rabbit hole and off-topic.  But you could write your output to a file and read it back in, if you had to, is my point.  You might not have to.  Once you extricate the code that is doing the data-grabbing into its own process, you'll probably be able to get around the error.  But as long as it's tied to the browser security settings, it's going to appear and be a problem, though, so long as that setting stays disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, search everywhere on the internet for solution, most advising to change IE security settings etc, which doesn't really work (though solution keeps on circulating).

Here's a simple solution to a complex problem.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")

clicked = 1
Set connect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
If clicked = 1 Then
    objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    clicked = 0
End If
```