# HTA : "Safety Settings on this computer prohibit accessing a data source on another domain"

Tags: hta

I am dealing with the same error message (as the subject) like two other threads:
[Suppress ADO Security Warning in JavaScript/HTM Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778918/suppress-ado-security-warning-in-javascript-htm-page) and 
[How to create intranet website accessing database dynamically without server or server side scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729210/how-to-create-intranet-website-accessing-database-dynamically-without-server-or)
but my application runs on the local computer only, it has nothing to do with any network or remote database.

The problem happens on some of my users' computer only. I have simplified the program to 1.js and 1.hta as listed below. Run 1.js through command line "cscript.exe 1.js" works fine on the users' computer (Windows 7). But run 1.hta on the same computer got the error "Safety Settings on this computer prohibit accessing a data source on another domain". 1.js and 1.hta are nearly the same!

The line that makes the problem is calling : ado.LoadFromFile("1.hta");
I have to use ADO instead of fso (Scripting.FileSystemObject), because fso can't access utf-8.

==== 1.js ===========

```
// run me through a DOS box command line : cscript.exe 1.js
var ado; 
ado = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
var data;
ado.CharSet = "utf-8";
ado.Open();
ado.LoadFromFile("1.js");
data = ado.ReadText();
ado.Close();
WScript.echo(data);
```

==== 1.hta ==========

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="Debug" 
   caption="yes" 
   maximizebutton="no" 
   minimizebutton="no" 
   sysmenu="yes" 
   BORDERSTYLE="complex"
   BORDER="thick"
/>
<TITLE>HTA - Debug</TITLE>
<script language="JScript">
var ado; 
ado = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
var data;
ado.CharSet = "utf-8";
ado.Open();
ado.LoadFromFile("1.hta");
data = ado.ReadText();
ado.Close();
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H2>HTA - Debug, try to read my own source code "1.hta"</H2>
<div id=sourcecode></div>
<script language="JScript"> sourcecode.innerText=data;</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

1.hta works fine on all Windows7, windows 8, windows 10 computers I can find. To make sure someone who can help me would be able to 100% reproduce the problem, I have found that 1.hta always failed on Windows XP. That's the only way I can reproduce the problem. We have tried to change IE's security settings, it doesn't work for either fixed the computer in ill or push any healthy computer into illness. I believe HTA does not refer to IE's settings.

Why is this happening on some computers? Point me any hint would be very much appreciated.

Comment: "I believe HTA does not refer to IE's settings." You're wrong, they are.

Comment: I wish HTA (actually mshta.exe) refers to IE's settings, so I can try to change them and pray for different results. Actually I did that already, I'll try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked well for me! tnx!

Modify the internet options in IE:

Go to Internet options -- Security Tab -- Select Internet and Local Intranet -- click Custom Level (button ) -- Miscellaneous -- select enable for Access data source across domains.

After that I reopened theQLIKVIEW model.

For me it worked..

Good Luck

Comment: Wow, a long awaited answer, thanks. I realized the problem was on Windows 7 and older Windows that means Windows 8 and 10 are ok. So I have given up supporting outdated Windows versions. If your solution worked for Windows 7 then it's nice to be confirmed.

Comment: I remember that the problem happened on only *some* Windows 7 computers.

Comment: @H.C.Chen Probably had nothing to do with the OS and everything to do with this setting.  I'm on 2 different Win 7 Pro computers - on one it works, on another, I get the error above.  Unfortunately, on both computers, each are controlled by different domain GPOs, and are on separate domains.  On one, I'm an admin, and the "Access data source across domains" is "Not Configured". On our other one, I can't view it because I'm not an admin, but I suspect it's locked down.

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778918/suppress-ado-security-warning-in-javascript-htm-page/47824528#47824528  as this isn't simple if you are not able to affect security settings in the browser because of GPOs.

Comment: It is worked when i got this error because of Olap Cube technology